# "Unknown named parameter" incomprehensible error

Tags: php, php-8, named-parameters

I am building several very similar objects and it works for all of them, except one.

The error trace is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $hymnus in /THEROUTE/src/App/Models/Completorium.php:27 Stack trace: 
#0 /THEROUTE/src/App/Domain/Infrastructure/Mapper/Breviarium/PdoBreviariumMapper.php(397): App\Models\Completorium->__construct('completorium', Object(App\Models\Kyrie), Object(App\Models\Hymnus), Object(App\Models\Psalmodia), Object(App\Models\LectioBrevis), Object(App\Models\CanticumEvangelicum), Object(App\Models\LHOratio), Object(App\Models\Conclusio)) 
#1 /THEROUTE/src/App/Domain/Infrastructure/Mapper/Breviarium/PdoBreviariumMapper.php(47): App\Domain\Infrastructure\Mapper\Breviarium\PdoBreviariumMapper->completorium(Object(stdClass)) 
#2 /THEROUTE/src/App/Domain/Infrastructure/Repository/Breviarium/BreviariumRepository.php(21): App\Domain\Infrastructure\Mapper\Breviarium\PdoBreviariumMapper->getData(Array) 
#3 /THEROUTE/src/App/Domain/Service/Breviarium/BreviariumService.php(36): App\Domain\Infrastructure\Repository\Breviarium\BreviariumRepository->getData(Array) 
#4 /THEROUTE/src/App/Controllers/Home.php(44): App\Domain\Service\Breviarium\BreviariumService->getData() 
#5 [internal function]: App\Controllers\Home->getFromServerAction() 
#6 /THEROUTE/src/Core/Controller.php(48): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#7 /THEROUTE/src/Core/Router.php(124): Core\Controller->__call('getFromServer', Array) 
#8 /THEROUTE/index.php(57): Core\Router->dispatch('') 
#9 {main} thrown in /THEROUTE/src/App/Models/Completorium.php on line 27
```

The relevant parts of the code:

#### PdoBreviariumMapper

The line `397` is: `new \App\Models\Completorium(`, and I passing one named parameter `hymnus` correctly at: `hymnus: new \App\Models\Hymnus("Lorem ipsum"),`:

```
            new \App\Models\Completorium(
                typus: $r->hora,
                kyrie: new \App\Models\Kyrie($r->kyrieID,$r->kyrie),
                hymnus: new \App\Models\Hymnus("Lorem ipsum"),
                psalmodia:
                    new \App\Models\Psalmodia(
                        $r->psalmodiaTypus,
                        (object) [
                            'antiphons' => $r->antiphons,
                            'psalmus' => $r->psalmus,
                            'psalmusPericopa' => $r->psalmusPericopa,
                            'epigraphs' => $r->epigraphs,
                            'themes' => $r->themes,
                            'parts' => $r->parts,
                          ]
                      ),
                lectioBrevis:
                    new \App\Models\LectioBrevis(
                        $r->lectioBrevis,
                        $r->brevisPericopa,
                        new \App\Models\ResponsoriumBrevis(
                            $r->brevisResponsorium,
                            $r->brevisResponsoriumTypus)
                        ),
                canticumEvangelicum:
                    new \App\Models\CanticumEvangelicum(
                    6,
                    array(new \App\Models\Antiphona(0,$r->canticumEvangelicum))),

                oratio:
                    new \App\Models\LHOratio($r->oratio),
                conclusio:
                    new \App\Models\Conclusio($r->antiphonaMariam)

            )
```

#### Completorium

The line `27` is: `typus:$typus,`

```
namespace App\Models;

class Completorium extends \App\Models\LiturgiaTypus implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private Kyrie $kyrie;
    private LectioBrevis $lectioBrevis;
    private CanticumEvangelicum $canticumEvangelicum;
    private Conclusio $conclusio;
    private bool $isPrimaVesperas=false;

    public function __construct
    (
        string $typus,
        Kyrie $kyrie,
        Hymnus $hymnus,
        Psalmodia $psalmodia,
        LectioBrevis $lectioBrevis,
        CanticumEvangelicum $canticumEvangelicum,
        LHOratio $oratio,
        Conclusio $conclusio
    )
    {
        parent::__construct
        (
            typus:$typus,
            hymnus:$hymnus,
            psalmodia:$psalmodia,
            oratio:$oratio
        );

        $this->kyrie=$kyrie;
        $this->lectioBrevis=$lectioBrevis;
        $this->canticumEvangelicum=$canticumEvangelicum;
        $this->conclusio=$conclusio;
    }
    public function jsonSerialize():mixed{
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

#### Hymnus

```
namespace App\Models;

class Hymnus implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private string $hymnus;
    public function __construct(string $hymnus)
    {
        $this->hymnus=$hymnus;
    }
    public function jsonSerialize():mixed{
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this error. I have similar code for other classes that works fine.

Comment: I don't know if named parameters are case sensitive. Try keeping them all the same case.

Comment: @aynber `lectioBrevis` and others work in similar cases. The error is only here.

Comment: Can I suggest breaking down this huge piece of code into a more manageable way - the 'line' `new \App\Models\Completorium(` would probably be easier to debug if you created variables with the various parts before passing them to the constructor.  Currently (as you've found out) it's difficult to know where exactly the error is coming from.

Comment: @NigelRen I understand your point. I'm doing it like this to save memory by assigning objects to variables unnecessarily. For debugging, I can check the contents of `$r` in this case.

Comment: So how much memory do you save compared to the time it saves in maintaining code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the `\App\Models\LiturgiaTypus` class. Does it have a `hymnus` parameter in the constructor?

Because it could very well cause this error too:

```php
parent::__construct
        (
            typus:$typus,
            hymnus:$hymnus,
            psalmodia:$psalmodia,
            oratio:$oratio
        );
```

Comment: OMG, that was the mistake! I was mistakenly extending the class from another that didn't have the `hymnus` parameter in its constructor. Thank you so much!